# ORA-00904: "2022-01-20": invalid identifier

Tags: python, django, oracle

I'm having a problem with the output of the Search Records Between Two Date Range From Database.

Below is my code snippet:

I await your help:

```
def mostraDate(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            fromDate = request.POST.get('fromDate')
            toDate = request.POST.get('toDate')
            cursor = Sms.objects.raw('select process_id, date_received,originator_msisdn, error_code from sms where date_replyed between "'+fromDate+'"and"'+toDate+'"')
            #cursor = Sms.objects.raw('''select process_id, date_received,originator_msisdn, error_code from sms where date_replyed between  ''', [fromDate] ,'''and''' ,[fromDate])
            return render(request, 'mostraDate.html', {"data": cursor})
        else:
            displaydate= Sms.objects.order_by('date_received').reverse()
            paginator = Paginator(displaydate, 5)
            page = request.GET.get('page')
            displaydate = paginator.get_page(page)
        return render(request, 'mostraDate.html', {"data": displaydate})
```

Comment: Can you share the `Sms` model? Why do you use raw queries?

Comment: You must enclose strings in 'single quotes' and escape names in "double quotes". Use `'` around your date, not `"` and use the TO_DATE function for [date literals](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_CVTACF6PQMV4XQAOXYJNSI365.html) in Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass both parameters and work with:

```
def mostraDate(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'fromDate' in request.POST and 'toDate' in request.POST:
        displaydate = Sms.objects.raw(
            'SELECT process_id, date_received,originator_msisdn, error_code'
            'FROM sms'
            'WHERE date_replyed BETWEEN %s AND %s',
            [request.POST['fromDate'], request.POST['toDate']]
        )
    else:
        displaydate = Sms.objects.order_by('-date_received')
        paginator = Paginator(displaydate, 5)
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        displaydate = paginator.get_page(page)
    return render(request, 'mostraDate.html', {'data': displaydate})
```

But there is no need to use a *raw* query. In fact by doing this you lose the power to order, filter, and pagiante this further. You can filter with:

```
def mostraDate(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'fromDate' in request.POST and 'toDate' in request.POST:
        displaydate = Sms.objects.filter(date_replyed__range=(request.POST['fromDate'], request.POST['toDate']))
    else:
        displaydate = Sms.objects.order_by('-date_received')
        paginator = Paginator(displaydate, 5)
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        displaydate = paginator.get_page(page)
    return render(request, 'mostraDate.html', {'data': displaydate})
```

Typically you filter however with a GET request, a POST request is normally used to make state changes like logging in/out, creating/updating/deleting an entity, etc. A GET request is usually used to *retrieve* data. This can be all data, or a filtered variant. A GET request is thus more appropriate here.

Comment: Hello Willem Van Onsem,

Both snippets work... Thank you very much.

you can include in the second snippet the join of two tables ?

Comment: @MaleboNhanga: yes, see *making queries* for more information on making JOINs, etc. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/

Comment: Hello Willem Van Onsem,

Thanks for the help...

We are together...